# Nginx server with both HTTP and HTTPS, browser selecting HTTP

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https, uwsgi

I'm deploying a web on an Nginx server. Nginx is configured with both http and https versions, like this:

```
upstream stream {
    server unix:///home/project/project.sock;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key server.key;

    server_name server.com;
    server_name *.server.com;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    charset utf-8;

    # Main
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass stream;

        # Parametros de uWSGI
        uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO                      $document_uri;
        uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME    https;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server.com;
    server_name *.server.com;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    charset utf-8;

    # Main
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  stream;

        # Parametros de uWSGI
        uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO                      $document_uri;
        uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME    http;
    }
}
```

All works correctly, but the browser is always selecting the HTTP version when you type server.com, and I want it to select the HTTPS version by default.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found,

Turns out it is possible to have both HTTP and HTTPS servers and choose HTTPS by default. I just had to mix the two servers of the conf file in one, just like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    ssl_certificate certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key server.key;

    server_name server.com;
    server_name *.server.com;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    charset utf-8;
...
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that stops a browser from requesting a HTTP connection?

Comment: @solarissmoke I guess it's because of the "default_server" tag

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to serve over HTTPS, then you need to redirect all HTTP requests in your HTTP server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

You can then remove all the other config you have in your HTTP server as it will never be used.

Comment: I need both versions, because I don't want the API to use HTTPS.

Comment: In that case you can't prevent a browser from fetching over HTTP. You could consider keeping your API on a separate HTTP-only subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control what the browser does (unfortunately); by default if the user doesn't type the *scheme* (that's the technical name for the `http://` part of the URL); then the browser will default to http.

If you want to serve the site only over https://, you have to redirect all requests to the https:// version.

You have to be careful here, if you implement a blind redirect as suggested by [solarissmoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33279171/790387), any POST requests will fail and not redirect appropriately.

A more compatible approach to redirection is to check the type of request:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
      if ($request_method = GET) {
        rewrite  ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
      }
      return 405;
    }
}
```

You can then add further checks to redirect only the traffic you want to https.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the following approach:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.yourdomain.com *.yourdomain.com;
    rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

What is does is basically redirecting the connection to a https (secure ssl) if the connection is normal http.
I hope it helps.